# ¿Cómo utilizar MOD en Java?

Tags: java

Me podrían ayudar a realizar un programa en JAVA. En el cual ingreso cualquier numero y de como resultado que números se pueden dividir entre `5,3,2` sin dejar residuos. por ejemplo, si ingreso `10` me de los números entre los cuales se pueda dividir. usando `(MOD)`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es el operador módulo `%`.

Ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(10 % 2); // 0
System.out.println(10 % 3); // 1
System.out.println(10 % 5); // 0
```

Comment: int num;
       Scanner nume= new Scanner (System.in);
          System.out.println("Total de numeros a dividir");
      num=nume.nextInt()
      do{
         if(num%5==0){
         System.out.println("Los numeros que se dividen entre 5 son: /"+num );   
       }

Comment: @jazmin ajá, y ¿cuál es tu duda o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Este método devuelve un ArrayList con todos los valores que pueden ser divisores de un número dado sin residuos.

El código controla que el número no sea `0` o un número negativo.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/JZPH32903)**</kbd>

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(numDivisores(10));
    }

    public static List<Integer> numDivisores(int intValor)
    {
        if (intValor<=0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No funciona para cero o números negativos");
        }else{
            List<Integer> lstDivisores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            lstDivisores.add(1);
            int i;
            for (i = 2; i <= intValor / 2; i++) 
            {
                if (intValor % i == 0) 
                {
                    lstDivisores.add(i);
                }
            }
            return lstDivisores;
        }
    }

}
```

---

Por ejemplo para `10` el resultado sería:

```
[1, 2, 5]
```